# Change configuration file location in AppFabric Cache

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

I have a two-hosts AppFabric cache cluster. The configuration file is located on one of the servers (not ideal, I know...)
I want to move the configuration file to other location. How can I re-configure the two hosts to get their config info from the new location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the appfab config wizard again.